# Can somebody make a licence → license tag synonym?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The UK spelling of the noun is "licence", and US "license". The standard for Stack Exchange seems to be US for tags:
[What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Please could someone with enough reputation create the synonym?

Comment: Actually, in much of the rest of the world, 'license' and 'licence' are two different words (as with "practise" and "practice"). They follow the same rules as 'advise' and 'advice' - which, thankfully, US English kept separate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Since no one on the site has the 1250 reputation required to suggest a tag synonym (And no one would have for at least a few more days).</s>

Your best bet would be to flag for moderator attention, and hope that one of the Community Managers see it.

Looks like the managers hath heard our prayers.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

[licence](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) will now always become [license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license). :D